# How to take a dot product of vectors “in equations”

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, physics

I know the terminology is very weird and probably misled many people form what I’m actually asking, but I don’t know any better way to describe it...

Why is the dot product of $\ b_1 $ and $\ b_2 $ equal to equation below? How did they even get those values?

Can someone guide me through the steps to get the answer?

$\vec b_1 = \vec c_1 \cos \theta + \vec c_2 \sin \theta$

$\vec b_2 = \vec c_2 \cos \theta - \vec c_1 \sin \theta$

$\vec b_1 \cdot \vec b_2 = -(\vec c_1^2 - \vec c_2^2)\sin \theta \cos \theta + \vec c_1 \cdot \vec c_2(\cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta) = 0$

[the equation in an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjUjx.jpg)

[edit 1] wrote out the equation in MathJax

[edit 2] forgot to mention that $ b_1 $ and $b_2$ are assumed to be perpendicular

Comment: Dot product is distributive over addition, so you can just expand the product.

Comment: Please [make your question visible](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992). You cannot "convert" that link into [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) but you **can** type it in mathjax.

Comment: [MathJax quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @eyeballforg I still don't understand what the simplified version of the dot product would be. I don't see any components of the vectors, can you please point them out?

Comment: @Hasith when eyeballfrog says “expand the product,” he doesn’t mean that you should write the product out in terms of its components

Comment: E.g., $(s\vec x + t\vec y)\cdot \vec z=s\vec x\cdot\vec z + t\vec y\cdot\vec z$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I get understand now thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given $\vec b_1$ and $\vec b_2$ are perpendicular and their dot product is 0, we have:
$$ \vec b_1\cdot\vec b_2=(\vec c_1\cos\theta+\vec c_2\sin\theta)\cdot(\vec c_2\cos\theta -\vec c_1\sin\theta)=0$$
$$ \Rightarrow \vec c_1\cdot\vec c_2 \cos^2\theta - |\vec c_1|^2 \sin\theta\cos\theta +|\vec c_2|^2\sin\theta\cos\theta-\vec c_1\cdot\vec c_2 \sin^2\theta=0$$ 
$$\Rightarrow \vec c_1\cdot\vec c_2(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta)-(|\vec c_1|^2-|\vec c_2|^2)\sin\theta\cos\theta=0$$
Notice that $\vec c_1 \cdot \vec c_2 $ is just a scalar quantity